# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ta_Kullanici' with unique index 'IX_ta_Kullanici'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I try to develop a program for insert datas from excel table to SqlServer.
I had an error when I try to insert data to sqlserver. That is my error message here

> "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ta_Kullanici' with
>   unique index 'IX_ta_Kullanici'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

ID is unque and autoincrement In my table.

Thanks for your help! :)

A part of my code is here;

```
 if (!check)
                    {
                        kul = new ta_Kullanici();
                        hata = new KullaniciHata();
                        hata.AdSoyad = kullanicilar.Rows[i][7].ToString() + " " + kullanicilar.Rows[i][8].ToString();
                        hatalar.Add(hata);

                        kul.kul_ad = kullanicilar.Rows[i][7].ToString();
                        kul.kul_soyad = kullanicilar.Rows[i][8].ToString();
                        foreach (var bolge in bolgeler)
                        {
                            if (kullanicilar.Rows[i][1].ToString().ToLower().IndexOf(bolge.bolge_ad.ToLower()) != -1)
                            {
                                kul.kul_bolge_Id = bolge.bolge_Id;
                            }
                        }
                        kul.kul_ikTar = DateTime.Now;
                        kul.kul_statu = true;
                        kul.kul_guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        kul.kul_ikIP = "127.0.0.1";
                        kul.kul_ik_kul_Id = 5;
                        kul.kul_TCKNo = kullanicilar.Rows[i][9].ToString();
                        kul.kul_kulAd = kullanicilar.Rows[i][6].ToString();
                        kul.kul_tip_enm = 2;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kullanicilar.Rows[i][9].ToString()))
                        {
                            kul.kul_sifre = kullanicilar.Rows[i][9].ToString();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            kul.kul_sifre = "123123";
                        }

                        checkList.Add(kul);
                        db.ta_Kullanici.Add(kul);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        hatalar.Remove(hata);
                    }
```

Comment: What is the name of the index which refer to your primary key in database ? By default it is something like PK_dbo.Kullanici. It seems it is violation of another index, not primary key

Comment: On which column index IX_ta_Kullanici is created in database, this column can not be duplicate?

Comment: yes. But it's not obligatory just one column, a few also possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the table in question `dbo.ta_Kullanici` and see what column the index named `IX_ta_Kullanici` is on.

The index in question is a **unique index**, meaning that it will **not** allow any duplicate values for the column(s)

Remember that this index could be on any column in the table and is not limited to the Primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the issue is that the column has an index of Unique key and what that index does is that it makes sure duplicate values do not get repeated on the column, to change that what you can do is to go to Management studio, go to the table that has that column, right-click on the column and click to modify. A screen will appear with all the columns displayed. right-click the small box beside the column and select indexes/keys. Then you will see a IsUnique property. set it to 'NO'.